# Compiling with boost returns "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, c++17

I would love to say that I have one problem, but actually it is all becoming a big mess.

I was trying to write some scripts in c++ to practice the use of the language and I tried to use boost/program_options to handle my script arguments. (I'm from MacOS Sonoma)

I both downloaded the library with brew and from the website in this order, then I added the library to VSCode IncludePath option. (For the brew version I put `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include/` and for the zip one I put `/Users/micle/Downloads/boost_1_83_0/`)
Of course I didn't add them both together. I tried first with one and then with the other.

For both of them I got the same problems:

- When I'm including the library, intellisense works and helps me looking for the correct header file (boost/program_options.hpp), but when I run it with the run button the compilation fails telling me `'boost/program_options.hpp' file not found`
- When I try to compile with the command `g++ prove.cpp -std=c++17` I get this:

```
  "boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()", referenced from:
      _main in prove-8fbb56.o
  "boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length", referenced from:
      _main in prove-8fbb56.o
  "boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in prove-8fbb56.o
  "boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in prove-8fbb56.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added the library to the c++ include path from my .zshrc with this line: 
`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/Users/micle/Downloads/boost_1_83_0/:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to link with the `boost_program_options` library too: `g++ prove.cpp -std=c++17 -lboost_program_options`

Comment: just tried. It returned ```ld: library not found for -lboost_program_options
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Comment: FYI -- *I was trying to write some scripts in c++* -- In C++, the term that is used is *program*, not *script*.

Comment: You are right and I know that. I just used it wrongly to mean that I'm writing just a little program that creates me one folder with two files instead of a big program. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You need to add the path to where the boost libraries are installed when compiling too: `-Lpath_to_the_boost_direcory`

Comment: @TedLyngmo where should them be? I tried like this, but nothing changed: ```g++ prove.cpp -std=c++17 -L/Users/micle/Downloads/boost_1_83_0/boost/ -lboost_program_options ```

Comment: Sesrch for it. It's probably in a directory cslled `lib` or `lib64`

Comment: I finally did it. I reinstalled it from brew and I used the lib directory I found there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve the problem thanks to @TedLyngmo. I reinstalled the brew version of the library and I compiled with `g++ prove.cpp -std=c++17 -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/lib -lboost_program_options`

Gonna start studying makefile to not having to write it all every time.
Thanks!